# How do i use gradle plugin generated from shared logic jar in another project?

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, gradle-plugin

I have a Gradle 8 project with a build-logic folder.
I was able to create a jar for that module and define it as a dependency in a separate project but I'm unable to apply the plugin.

[image: Project A (Source of Build-logic Jar)]

now I'm trying to import it into a separate project so that I can reuse the commons plugin. I can add it as a dependency and can see it being loaded but I cannot apply the plugin.

I have pushed it to mavel local and trying to use it in another project.

````
```
> Task :build-logic:publishPluginMavenPublicationToMavenLocal
Multiple publications with coordinates 'com.test.build-logic:spring-base-starter-build-logic:1.0.0' are published to repository 'mavenLocal'. The publications 'mavenJava' in project ':build-logic' and 'pluginMaven' in project ':build-logic' will overwrite each other!
```
````

The jar seems to be loading fine in another project.

````
```
dependencies {
    constraints {
        // Define dependency versions as constraints
        implementation lib.apacheTextCommons
        implementation(lib.spring_boot_starter_web)
    }
    implementation lib.spring_boot_starter_web
    testImplementation lib.spring_boot_starter_test
    implementation lib.jackson_databind
    implementation lib.openApiGradlePlugin
    //works fine .ie. loads jar
    implementation "com.test.build-logic:spring-base-starter-build-logic:1.0.0"
    implementation lib.javaxValidator
    implementation lib.javaxAnnotation
    implementation lib.swaggerAnnotation
    integrationTestImplementation lib.junitJupiterEngine
    integrationTestImplementation lib.junitJupiterApi
}```
````

But I'm unable to figure out how to `apply` it.

````
```
plugins {
    // Apply the java Plugin to add support for Java.
    id 'java'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management'
    id "org.openapi.generator"
    id "openapi-gen"
    id "com.test.java-common-conventions"
    id 'dependencies'
}
```
````

gives the following error:

````
```
An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'com.meili.java-application-conventions']
> Failed to apply plugin 'com.meili.java-application-conventions'.
   > Failed to apply plugin 'com.meili.java-common-conventions'.
      > org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin with id 'com.test.java-common-conventions' not found.
```
````

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking
a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). What does "not working"
mean? Please be specific.

Comment: @cfrick sorry for the incorrect formatting kind sir! i have updated the question with actual code and error logs

Answer (score 0):

To apply the plugin in this form, you won't be able to do it using the `plugins` block<sup>1</sup>.

However it should be possible to do so using the old `apply` syntax. First, however, you must add it to the buildscript classpath:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.test.build-logic:spring-base-starter-build-logic:1.0.0"
    }
}
```

Then it should be available to be applied:

```
apply plugin: 'com.test.java-common-conventions'
```

---

<sup>1</sup>If you want to use the `plugins` block, the plugin needs to be packaged so that Gradle can find it by id. Practically, the way to do this is to [write a class plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html#sec:writing_a_simple_plugin) and use the Java Gradle Plugin to package it in this way.